# Emploi de "frappe, mais écoute" ('strike, if you will; but hear') (grec: pataxon men, akouson de)

Tags: expressions, traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, grec

En grec ancien, on dit

> πάταξον μέν, ἄκουσον δέ (pataxon men, akouson de) = strike, if you will; but hear = frappe, mais écoute

Voici un peu de contexte historique : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurybiade

Aujourd'hui, on l'utilise toujours en grec moderne pour exprimer le droit incontestable de chacun d'exprimer son opinion, aussi audacieuse soit-elle.
La tournure française *frappe, mais écoute* pourrait-elle employée dans un contexte similaire ? Est-elle idiomatique ? Quelles autres tournures existent aussi pour exprimer une idée similaire ?

Comment: ἀνἑρ ἄπολίς va! ;-)

Comment: "strike if you will but hear" means nothing in English.

Comment: @Lambie https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Themistocles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si l'expression de Thémistocle a pu être utilisée en France à une époque où les gens cultivés étudiaient le latin et le grec, la culture classique s'est très largement perdue de nos jours, même parmi ceux ayant fait des études longues. Au XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle la citation rapportée par Plutarque ne serait non seulement pas reconnue mais peut-être pas comprise. Nous pouvons supposer que dans la Grèce actuelle les allusions à la culture antique sont encore vivaces, il en est tout autrement en France et il faut donc employer des mots qui ne puissent pas prêter à confusion.

Dans la Grèce antique, comme d'ailleurs longtemps dans l'histoire du monde occidental, et dans certaines parties du monde actuel, la violence tenait une place qu'une partie de la société occidentale réprouve de nos jours (du moins extérieurement). 
La violence  va à l'encontre des principes éducatifs dans de nombreux endroits et il me semble impensable que l'on puisse faire la citation en employant les mêmes mots. 
C'est d'ailleurs dans le contexte éducatif qu'on peut trouver des allusions à cette citation de nos jours. On y cite parfois Lacan qui a utilisé cette citation<sup>1</sup> dans son séminaire sur les psychoses (1955-1956) :

> Quand on reçoit une gifle, il y a bien d’autres façons de répondre que de pleurer, on peut la rendre, et aussi tendre l’autre joue, on peut aussi dire – *Frappe, mais écoute*. <sup>2</sup>

Je ne connais en français aucune expression toute faite pour communiquer l'idée de  *πάταξον μέν, ἄκουσον δέ*  et où ne s'exprimerait aucune incitation à la violence physique. On peut que rendre l'idée en fabriquant soi-même des expressions, par exemple :

- Écoute d'abord, ensuite tu pourras réagir.
- Fâche-toi si tu veux mais commence par écouter.
- Écoute d'abord, réprouve après.
- Écoute d'abord, rétorque ensuite.

etc.

On peut aussi citer [la phrase de Didier Deschamps](http://sports.tv5monde.com/coupe-monde-2018-bleus-didier-deschamps-meritent-de-jouer-7565617.html) :

> Chacun est libre de dire ce qu’il veut et d’assumer ses propos.

---

Voici quelques citations faisant référence aux paroles de Thémistocle dans des écrits de langue française. Comme on le voit, la source est quasiment toujours citée (sauf pour Hugo et de Mirabeau) et presque toutes sont antérieures au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

- Voltaire dans *[Les Scythes](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Voltaire_-_%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_Garnier_tome6.djvu/311)* (1767) fait dire à Athamare, avec en note une référence à Alcibiade, :

  > Il me faut ou mourir ou régner à tes pieds. Frappe, mais entends-moi.
- Mirabeau dans une [lettre à un ami](http://collections-aristophil.com/html/fiche.jsp?id=10017948&np=&lng=fr&npp=150&ordre=&aff=&r=) en 1784 :

  > Je m'en veux pourtant de ne t'avoir pas écrit depuis plusieurs jours, et je ne m'absous pas en me disant que tu me dois une réponse; je me dis au contraire que tout autre que le philosophique Toi seroit inquiet de moi ou fâché contre moi. Dans les deux cas je puis te dire: frappe mais écoute.
- Flaubert la mentionne dans [une correspondance](https://flaubert.univ-rouen.fr/jet/public/correspondance/trans.php?corpus=correspondance&id=10363&mot=&action=M) adressée à un ami (1859) :

  > après mille réflexions, j'ai envie d'inventer une autographie chouette, afin de donner de moi une bonne opinion 1° dès l’âge le plus tendre j'ai dit tous les mots célèbres dans l’histoire – « nous combattrons à l'ombre – retire-toi de mon soleil – quand vous aurez perdu vos enseignes et guidons – frappe mais écoute, etc. ! »
- Hugo dans [un discours](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Hugo_-_Actes_et_paroles_-_volume_5.djvu/204) en 1871 :

  > Ma liberté, c’est ma dignité. Frappe, mais écoute. Insultez-moi, mais laissez-moi libre.
- Jules Destrée dans une [lettre au roi](http://www.histoire-des-belges.be/au-fil-du-temps/epoque-contemporaine/lettre-au-roi-sur-la-separation-de-la-wallonie-et-de-la-flandre) sur la séparation de la Wallonie et de la Flandre (1912) :

  > Pour ma part, pour avoir dit qu'il y avait une question wallonne, j'ai déjà à choisir entre « criminel » et « hurluberlu ». J'en verrai d'autres. Je leur répondrai tranquillement, selon la leçon de Thémistocle : « Frappe, mais écoute. » La répression ou la négation ne sont donc point des remèdes dont Vous puissiez Vous satisfaire.
- Dans une tribune du journal *Le Monde* en 1976 :

  > Même aux hommes les plus puissants de ce monde, je peux répéter le mot du Grec menacé : « Frappe, mais écoute. » Charles Hélou (Ancien président de la République libanaise)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Que je fais brève et qu'il faudrait bien sûr replacer dans son contexte.

<sup>2</sup> L'italique est de l'auteur ce qui indique donc que c'est une citation. Ceux qui assistaient aux séminaires de Lacan et ceux qui lisent Lacan appartiennent à une toute petite minorité qui a les clés pour comprendre et qui n'est pas représentative de la majorité de la population.</sub>

Comment: Les propos de Lacan sont difficiles à comprendre, parfois, comme par exemple: Il fait clair quand il fait beau. Ce qui s'applique surtout à lui-même. Mais une fois qu'on a compris telle ou telle chose, on se rend compte à quel point il aimait exagérer ses propos. C'est dommage puisque *sa contribution énorme à la civilisation* aurait été plus grande sans son barroquisme parfois idiot.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une citation rapportée par Plutarque dans sa *Vie de Thémistocle, II, 3* et attribuée à Thémistocle, une citation reconnue ([Le monde](https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/citations/citation-14450.php)), et il n'y aurait aucune raison de ne pas l'utiliser, quitte à l'expliquer à qui ne comprend pas (si on en a le temps et si la situation qui nécessite de faire appel à une telle citation ménage quelque motivation dans ce sens !), mais elle n'est pas connue.

De ce fait, si on préfère rester dans les normes d'un échange rapide, sans ambiguïté, il vaudra mieux recourir à un autre moyen, bien que je doive le reconnaitre, c'est un mot qui peut se comprend plus ou moins de lui-même.

Le type de situation qui correspond n'est pas si rare et il est traité différemment par les gens qui adhèrent plus ou moins à l'esprit de « Frappez, mais écoutez ! ». Ils utilisent tout simplement une phrase au même effet qui sera en fait une explication sommaire de la citation ; voici des exemples.

- Vous pouvez me frapper mais d'abord il faudra que vous sachiez ce que j'ai à dire !
- Frappez, ça ne m'empêchera pas de dire ce que je veux !
- Que vous frappiez ou non vous allez savoir ce j'ai à vous dire !

Comment: Ce n'est pas de Plutarque puisque c'est Thémistocle. (Au moins 500 ans avant...)

Comment: @aCOSwt Merci de signaler cette erreur.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne connais pas de phrase française strictement équivalente, peut-être en raison de ce que cette injonction de Thémistocle s'est transformée en une phrase qui s'est beaucoup plus répandue :

*Taper d'abord, discuter ensuite* et autres variantes (cogner, tuer... / parler, causer)

Dont les adverbes, au-delà de l'intention de Thémistocle, accentuent, au gré du contexte, la stupidité bornée de l'agresseur ou la nécessité de se fatiguer physiquement pour discuter plus calmement quand ce n'est pas l'absurdité générale.

Absurdité absurdité... ne dit-on pas couramment... *taper comme un sourd* ?

Dans une traduction française des propos de Thémistocle... j'aurais d'ailleurs écrit :

*Tape comme un sourd mais écoute, espèce de... espèce de... : patachon!* :-)

C'eût au moins été marrant!

Comment: En side note, si @Dimitris pouvait, en échange de ma très sçavante contribution m'expliquer comment le *citoyen indigne* de l'ancienne Grèce peut bien être devenu le *centre-ville* de la nouvelle aux dires de Google-translate, je lui en saurai gré.

Comment: Sorry! Je veux poser cette question à un colleague (parcours pluridisciplinaire: épistémologie, philosophie, sciences exactes).